# Is there an equivalent function in JPA to INSTR Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm using Eclipse link with JPA 2.1 , noting that I have an Oracle Query use  function "INSTR" with the feature of occurrence param.

Is there any equivalent to this method in JPA ?

Answer (score 1):

JPQL supports [`LOCATE`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL) function:

> **LOCATE**
>
> the index of the string within the string, optionally starting at a start index

Comment: sure its supported there, but what i need for example is to get the second occurrence of the specific character starting from index "x"